# How handle Informational waste

Tags: social-engineering

I do big tiding of my flat and I found out, that lot of my waste consists from boxes with my addresses and receipts from online store deliveries. What is the most easiest and also most efficient way to discard such type of waste at home?

Answer (score 1):

**Paper Format**

- Shred the copies with a cross-cut shredder or if the volume is large enough you could pay an organization to dispose of them for you. If you're really paranoid you can take your shreddings and mix them up across multiple recycling bags and dispose of them in different areas.
- Burn them (assuming that you have a facility to safely do that and you're not burning anything harmful to you or the environment such as plastic)

**Digital Format**

- Use software such as [DBAN](http://dban.org) or similar alternative that will overwrite your data with multiple passes to ensure it cannot be recovered
- If data is stored on an SSD note that the destruction process may differ and you'll want to ensure your product has a Secure SSD Erase feature
- You may also choose to open up the disks and physically destroy them for an added layer of protection

Comment: Although I shred, it is definitely, not easier than burning or using acid.  Shredders sound all well and good, but then you read the fine print.  So first you just buy the cheapest model, now it can only handle 2-4 pages at once if your lucky.  Then if you operate it according to the manual after <30 minutes of use you are supposed to let it cool down.  Not until you are spending $200+ can you get decent rates.  So you ignore the manufacturers suggestions, and burn the motor out.  A whole bottle of lighter fluid, and safe container is way less, and you can do a lot more at once.